# Logic to show Bootstrap popover acting abnormally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm having 2 weird issues with my popovers shown here in [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4v65ggos/27/)

1. After I have selected a day (in fullcalendar) and the popover shows, I click the day again to hide the popover, then I click again in the same day to show again, but no popover!. It's after I click to show, hide, then click to show again that I'm having issues.
2. When I click on an eventLimitClick event inside a day (April 20th in fiddle), then click on the day (April 20th). The popover hides after I click the day, but then doesn't show any popover for the day like it should.

Here is some of the logic, but please refer to the fiddle link above for working code.

```
var $calPopOver;

$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next', //today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
  },
  defaultView: 'month',
  editable: true,
  allDaySlot: false,
  selectable: true,
  eventLimit: 1,
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ManageSpaces/GetDiaryEvents/',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        start: start.format(),
        end: end.format(),
        id: $("#HiddenYogaSpaceId").val()
      },
      success: function(doc) {
        var events = [];
        $(doc).each(function() {
          events.push({
            title: "1 Event", //$(this).attr('title'),
            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
          });
        });
        callback(events);
      }
    });
  },

  eventLimitText: function(numberOfEvents) {
    return numberOfEvents + " Events";
  },

  eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo, jsEvent) {
    $(cellInfo.dayEl).popover({
      html: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      container: 'body',
      title: function() {
        return $("#events-popover-head").html();
      },
      content: function() {
        return $("#events-popover-content").html();
      }
    });

    //$(cellInfo.dayEl).popover('toggle');
    if ($calPopOver) {
      $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
    }
    $calPopOver = $(cellInfo.dayEl).popover('show');
  },
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) { //function (data, event, view) {
    //var s = cellInfo.segs;
    $("#eventDetails.collapse").collapse('toggle');

    if ($calPopOver)
      $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
  },
  dayClick: function(data, event, view) {
    $dayClickedDate = data.format();
    $(this).popover({
      html: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      container: 'body',
      title: function() {
        return $("#day-popover-head").html();
      },
      content: function() {
        return $("#day-popover-content").html();
      }
    });

    //$(this).popover('toggle');
    if ($calPopOver) {
      $calPopOver.popover('destroy');
    }
    $calPopOver = $(this).popover('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is really just a debug my code question. You better do that yourself.

Comment: maybe you can give me a pointer to do that? From my logic, on the events you can see, I'm destroying then showing a popover, so I'm not sure why the popover isn't showing after I call something.popover('show'). How would I debug an issue like that? Dev tools in browser or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look into these bootstrap examples. If you can manage to get a copy of the examples, it's simple a copy and paste scenario IMO.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Search for "Popovers popover.js" on this page and scroll a bit down for the examples.